# Is this a bash bug? (list directories with ls)

Tags: bash, ls

If I want to list all files and directories in the following directory :

```
[root@centos2 dir1]# tree
.
+-- dir2
    +-- coucou.txt

1 directory, 1 file
```

Why dir2 is not shown below? Only the file is shown.

```
[root@centos2 dir1]# ls -l *
total 0
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  2 18:20 coucou.txt
```

If I copy the directory and list, they are both shown :

```
[root@centos2 dir1]# cp -r dir2/ dir3
[root@centos2 dir1]# tree
.
+-- dir2
¦   +-- coucou.txt
+-- dir3
    +-- coucou.txt

2 directories, 2 files

[root@centos2 dir1]# ls -l *
dir2:
total 0
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  2 18:20 coucou.txt

dir3:
total 0
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  5 11:34 coucou.txt
```

Comment: To list directories use the `-d` switch as `ls -d */`

Comment: Try `echo *` and see what happens.  Pattern (glob) expansion is `bash`, `ls` is an external program and has nothing to do with `bash` (and has been around since the 1970s - do you really think you found a new bug in it?).   To see expansions as they happen use `set -o xtrace` (or simple `set -x`).  Use `set +o xtrace` or `set +x` to switch them off.

Comment: @cdarke I would have loved to find a new bug in it! ;) You are right the title of my question is not very appropriate. I should have asked about "ls" behaviour instead of talking about bash... Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not a bug; it's the expected behaviour of the shell to expand `*` to match everything. The `*` is replaced by a list of arguments, one for each matching path, **before** the command is run.

In your first example, `ls -l *`, the shell expands `*` to `dir2`, so your command is `ls -l dir2`. `ls` then just lists the contents of that directory, so you get your file `coucou.txt`.

In your second example, `*` is expanded to two arguments, `dir2` and `dir3`. In this case, the behaviour of `ls -l` is to separately list the contents of each directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the command like that `ls -l *` it's like you are writing the command for every element in your current directory, changing that `*` with the name of your element. And when you use the command `ls` and the argument is a directory, it lists the elements inside, not the directory itself.

I think you are looking for a recursive `ls` option, which is `-R`:

```
[root@centos2 dir1]#ls -lR
.:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  5 11:41 dir2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  5 11:41 dir3

./dir2:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  5 11:41 cocou.txt

./dir3:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec  5 11:41 cocou.txt
```